# Schedule Apex Class to users of a specific profile

Tags: apex, soql, send-email

I'm trying to send an email template to all users of a certain profile "Sales Ops".  I've found the following code and have created a scheduled Apex Class with it.  However, I'm not sure if I can use "and Profile.Name = 'Sales Ops'.

Does this look correct?  I'm new to Apex Classes so any hints or advice would be appreciated!

Here's my current code:

```
global class sendEmailToUSer implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        list<User> lstUser = [Select ID from User where isActive = true and Profile.Name = 'Sales Ops'];
        for(User iterator : lstUser) {
            EmailTemplate objTemp = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Campaign_Member_Report' limit 1];
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTemplateId(objTemp.Id);
            mail.setTargetObjectId(iterator.Id);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is valid SOQL syntax to query based upon the profile name.

You have a different issue, however. This code is completely unbulkified and will rapidly hit limits issues.

```
for(User iterator : lstUser) {
    EmailTemplate objTemp = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Campaign_Member_Report' limit 1];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setTemplateId(objTemp.Id);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(iterator.Id);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

You have a SOQL query inside your `for` loop. That's easy to fix. Just move

```
    EmailTemplate objTemp = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Campaign_Member_Report' limit 1];
```

outside the `for` loop, and the behavior will not change - except that you won't get a SOQL limit exception when you have 101 users in this profile.

You should also create a `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]` variable outside your `for` loop and accumulate messages there, rather than calling `Messaging.sendEmail()` each time through the loop. Then, call `Messaging.sendEmail()` with the whole list at the end of the method.

Note that you can only call `sendEmail()` [10 times in a transaction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section), so this is another place your code could fail with volume if not remedied.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'm such a beginner with code/Apex that I may just seek alternative routes at this point until I can learn some more about this subject.

Comment: @MattGodfroy, you could probably do this with Process Builder and Flow. If you could write up a detailed question with your objectives, you might post asking whether there is a good declarative-only solution.

Comment: Doug Ayer's Mass Action Scheduler app might help with that.

Comment: Headless flow is definitely a possibility and something I'm much more familiar working with.  I was just watching Doug's demo on his solution.  A requirement is you need to have Lightning enabled in your org which we currently do not :(  . I'm going to keep researching what I can find. If all else fails I might end up writing a more detailed question like you suggested.  Thanks again.

Comment: I believe you need Apex to use email templates, though. Of course, that could potentially be an `InvocableAction`.